# How to view the plain text format of the row based binarly logs

Tags: replication, mysqlbinlog

I have server with row based binary logging enabled on it. 
Recently while debugging an issue, I tried to view the content of the binary log from a specific position but it gave me the out put which is not readable.

```
Is there any way to see the output in plain text format ?
```

Here are the details that might be needed.

```
character_set of client/server/connection/result     latin1
Binlog format                                        ROW based
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the mysqlbinlog utility to dump the binary logs to SQL format:

```
mysqlbinlog /path/to/mysql-bin.0000 > /path/to/dump.sql
```

Typically, the binary logs are in `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: When I try this I get big sections of useless strings like BEGIN
Update_rows: table id 4358 flags: STMT_END_FBINLOG 'dQbeUhMBAAAAXgAAAE8ehQAAAAYRAAAAAAEAA2F